# JavaScript - Não consigo fazer com que o resultado no meu innerHTML seja igual ao do meu console.log. Na tentativa de apresentar vários dados

Tags: javascript, html5, json, api, objetos

Bíblia
    
        #resultado{
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            max-width: 335px;
            background-color: #397575;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
        }

## Procure o texto desejado:

```
<label for="escolhaLivro">Livro:</label>
<select name="escLivro" id="escolhaLivro">
    <option>Escolha o livro</option>
</select>

<label for="escolhaCap">Capítulo:</label>
<select name="escCap" id="escolhaCap"><option>Ecolha o capítulo</option></select>

<label for="escVer">Versão:</label>
<select name="escVer" id="escVer">
    <option value="nvi">Nova Versão Internacional-(NVI)</option>
    <option value="ra">Almeida Revista e Atualizada-(RA)</option>
    <option value="acf">Almeida Corrigida Fiel-(ACF)</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="procurar()">Procurar</button>

<div id="resultado">
    <p>Seu resultado aqui...</p>
</div>



<script src="biblia.js"></script>
```

```js
var urlLivros = `https://www.abibliadigital.com.br/api/books`

var capitulo = document.querySelector("#escolhaCap")

var livro = document.querySelector("#escolhaLivro")

var version = document.querySelector("#escVer")

var i = 0

livro.addEventListener("change", async function(){

    var urlcapitulos = `https://www.abibliadigital.com.br/api/books/${livro.value}`

    var request = await fetch(urlcapitulos)
    var response = await request.json()
    
    let options = ""
    
    while(i < response.chapters){
    i++
    options += `<option>`+i+`</option>`
    }
        
    capitulo.innerHTML = options
})

window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
    var request = await fetch(urlLivros)
    var response = await request.json()

   var options = document.createElement("optgroup")
    options.setAttribute("label", "Livros");

    response.forEach(lv => {
        options.innerHTML += `<option value=`+lv.abbrev.pt+`>`+lv.name+`</option>`
    })

    livro.append(options)
})

function procurar(){

      let url = `https://www.abibliadigital.com.br/api/verses/${version.value}/${livro.value}/${capitulo.value}`;

      fetch(url).then(function(response){
          response.json().then(apresentardados);
      })
  }

  function apresentardados(dados){

    console.log(dados)
    let  resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado");
    let n = 0

    
    if(dados.erro){

        resultado.innerHTML = `<p>Não foi possível localizar endereço!</p>`;

    }else{

        while(n < dados.chapter.verses){

            var resultado_text = dados.verses[n].text;
            var resultado_num = dados.verses[n].number;
            
            console.log(resultado_num, resultado_text)  

            resultado.innerHTML = `<p>${dados.book.name}</p> 
            <p>Capítulo: ${dados.chapter.number}</p>
            <p><strong>${resultado_num}</strong> -${resultado_text}</p>`

            n++ 
        }
            
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bíblia</title>
    <style>
        #resultado{
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            max-width: 335px;
            background-color: #397575;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Procure o texto desejado:</h1>

    <label for="escolhaLivro">Livro:</label>
    <select name="escLivro" id="escolhaLivro">
        <option>Escolha o livro</option>
    </select>

    <label for="escolhaCap">Capítulo:</label>
    <select name="escCap" id="escolhaCap"><option>Ecolha o capítulo</option></select>

    <label for="escVer">Versão:</label>
    <select name="escVer" id="escVer">
        <option value="nvi">Nova Versão Internacional-(NVI)</option>
        <option value="ra">Almeida Revista e Atualizada-(RA)</option>
        <option value="acf">Almeida Corrigida Fiel-(ACF)</option>
    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="procurar()">Procurar</button>

    <div id="resultado">
        <p>Seu resultado aqui...</p>
    </div>



    <script src="biblia.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Tudo bem André?!

André, esse problema é porque está sendo executado um **innerHtml** no momento de adicionar os demais versos, para resolver vamos usar o **appendChild** para ser adicionado os conteúdos dentro da **DIV resultado** sem que seja substituído o verso anterior.
Para deixar o código simplificado vamos usar o **map** nos versos(segue o código abaixo):

```
function apresentardados(dados) {

    let resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado");


    if (dados.erro) {

        resultado.innerHTML = `<p>Não foi possível localizar endereço!</p>`;

    } else {
        //Limpar a div
        resultado.innerHTML = "";

        dados.verses.map(x => {
            let DivVerses = document.createElement("div");
            let ContentVerses = document.createElement("p");
            let ContentVersesCap = document.createElement("p");

            ContentVersesCap.textContent = x.number;
            ContentVerses.textContent = x.text;
            DivVerses.style.margin = "10px";
            DivVerses.appendChild(ContentVersesCap);
            DivVerses.appendChild(ContentVerses);

            resultado.appendChild(DivVerses);
        });

    }
```

Espero que eu tenha ajudado, até a próxima!
**Bons estudos!**

Answer (score -2):

cara é que toda vez que passa pelo while ele substitui o que já havia sido vinculado no html, porque toda vez ele faz um innerhtml em cima.
Cria um array fora do while, dentro do while você percorre todo esse array e salvando conforme código abaixo, e fora do while você faz um innerHTML.

```
    let resultado_text[];
    let resultado_num[];
    
    while(n < dados.chapter.verses){
         resultado_text.push(dados.verses[n].text);
         let resultado_num.push(dados.verses[n].number)
    }
```